# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework application is using wrong SQL connection string

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, connection-string, webdeploy

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 web application that was originally created using VS2013 and uses Entity Framework 6 Code First, with data migrations. It has been working fine (in production) for almost a year and has been re-deployed numerous times, from Visual Studio, using Web Deploy.

Today, I opened the solution in VS2015 and redeployed a known working version of the codebase to production without any problems. However, after deployment, the production website suffered from the problems described in [this article](http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/04/how-to-fix-systemmethodaccessexception.html), which I solved by applying author's the recommended fixes.

After applying these fixes, I now have a new problem: an exception that suggests that the application is trying to access the database using the wrong connection string:

> Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed.

Within the details of the exception page, the cause of the problem is clarified:

> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory.

I'm puzzled by this because the application has a dedicated SQL Server instance that is accessed using a regular connection string. I've checked the `Web.config` generated by Web Deploy and it seems to be intact. It contains a named connection string that correctly references the production SQL Server instance, and the code (which hasn't changed) correctly instantiates an Entity Framework ApplicationContext using the named connection string.

Does anyone have any idea why this application now expects to create its own SQL Server instance or what I can do to debug this problem?

Many thanks for your suggestions,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try before making the web deploy:

- Check if the project that contains the connection string declaration (web.config) is setted as the 'startup project'.
- Rebuild the solution in release mode.
- In the Publish Web wizard, in Settings, expand File Publishing Options and check 'Remove additional files at destination' and 'Exclude files from App_Data folder'

Comment: Thanks - they were all logical suggestions but none of them has made any difference.